# Quero colocar imagem como plano de fundo do meu projeto HTML5, mas nao consigo! Como posso resolver?

Tags: html5, css3

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Esta definido a div. E mesmo assim nao funciona.

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]
Ja tentei colocar no body{..}, mas nao obtive sucesso tambem ):
Alguem me ajuda!!

Comment: Com body você fez assim `body         { background-image: url('im/fundo.jpg') }` ? se não aparecer é que o caminho da imagem está errado

Comment: Agora, ao invés de postar imagem, coloque o código, veja porque em https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/5483/manual-de-como-n%C3%83o-fazer-perguntas/5485#5485

Answer (score -3):

Olá, basta inserir o código:
background-image:url("img/imagem.png");
background-repeat:no-repeat;
height:2000px;
background-attachment:fixed;